# Animated 'show' without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I want to do a little animation on this latest website ii'm working on. Basically, I need one or two divs/paragraph show/hide based on onClick event on either radio buttons set or checkbox (then, if radio/check is value A, show div/p, if it's B then hide it)

The thing is, that this is all I would like to javascript-ify on that particular website, so jQuery looks like a little overkill (even the minified version)

Is there any **simple** [I can't stress this enough] way to do this either by *vanilla* JavaScript or some other minimal library [I'm generally looking for something <2kB for events and little animation (height)].

### Edit

Thanks to everyone, I just realized, that although some of the things I need to could be done via smart html+js, the rules of showing/hiding the right divs are so complicated, that it's worth of 30kB of including jQuery (even more if it's already cached from CDN), so I'll stick with jQuery. Cheers to everyone :)

### Edit

JS+CSS3 transition follow-up, it works :) http://jsfiddle.net/ygZM7/23/

JS:

```
var $setter = document.getElementById('setter');

$setter.onclick = function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('div1'),
        h = el.clientHeight;
        el.style.height = (h==200?100:200)+'px';
}
```

The only thing is: if height was previously not set (dynamic), first time you set it, the background flicks (goes from 0px height).

Comment: You could try loading jQuery from the Google CDN, there is a great chance that it will already be cached. I don't say you should do this, just wanted to add another option.

Comment: @bazmegakapa – I could, but that's option of last resort – CDN with fallback ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've came up with my own quick script.. here goes nothing:

```
var AnimationStep = 10; //pixels
var AnimationInterval = 100; //milliseconds

window.onload = function() {
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("Div1");
    oDiv.style.display = "block";
    var height = oDiv.clientHeight;
    oDiv.style.height = "0px";
    Animate(oDiv, height);
};

function Animate(element, targetHeight) {
    var curHeight = element.clientHeight;
    if (curHeight >= targetHeight)
        return true;
    element.style.height = (curHeight + AnimationStep) + "px";
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        Animate(element, targetHeight);
    }, AnimationInterval);
    return false;
}
```

This will "animate" element with id `Div1` and you can control the speed by playing with the two numbers on top: bigger *Step* means bigger chunk is displayed every time and smaller *Interval* means faster animation.
This code requires the following style to be applied on the element:

```css
#Div1 { display: none; overflow: hidden; }
```

And of course live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/BbWCp/

It should be pretty simple to animate the width as well (maybe even in the same time) to achieve "cooler" effect. :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll play with this (probably). And the animation isn't purely for effect – I chose it as an alternative to simply show div to keep the users from confusion (due to design of the form, just setting visible/hidden isn't the best solution) ^_^

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do the animation by updating the "height" of the element, thus making it sort-of a "slide down" (or "up" I guess) effect, it shouldn't be too hard. You just have to make small changes quickly with a timer.

```
<div id='animateMe' style='height: 0px; overflow: hidden'>
  blah blah blah
</div>

<script>
  (function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('animateMe');
    var curh = 0, finalh = 100;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (curh === finalh) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      }

      curh = curh + 1;
      div.style.height = curh + 'px';
    }, 50);
  })();
</script>
```

That's just a sample; you could wire the code up to an event handler or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS transitions. doesn't work in every browser but that's totally acceptable that users in IE7 don't have the exact same experience as users in Chrome/Safari/FF4.

Comment: Yes, but I want radio A to be tied to paragraph B and I though, that css3 transitions don't apply to js-changed values (e.g. style.height = 'YYpx')

Comment: re: javascript+css transition, it works. In OP is edit with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
   function swap(rad) {
       var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
       var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
       if (rad.value === "1") {
         p1.style.display = "none";
         p2.style.display = "block";
       } else {
         p1.style.display = "block";
         p2.style.display = "none";
       }
       return false;
   }
</script>

<label><input type="radio" name="r" value="1" onclick="swap(this)" />One</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r" value="2" onclick="swap(this)" />Two</label>
<p id="p1">Hi there</p>
<p id="p2">Hey there</p>
```

Comment: That's almost it, except: A. it doesn't animate [important] and B: it just swaps to things, but I need p1/p2 to hide/show based on 'checked' value of clicked radio/checkbox – although I could figure that one out, probably. Thanks anyway, I'd be glad if you could enhance the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I had the same question, but wanted to have the height of the element even if it is not set in the style, and even if the element has display: none. So my solution is to steal the element, make it invisible, place it somewhere unseen, make its display: block, measure its height using clientHeight, put it back into its original place with original settings and then do the sliding. Here it is:

```
    function slideElementIn(myid) {
      mydiv=    document.getElementById(myid);
      if(mydiv.style.display!="none")return;

        // clientHeight is zero when display is none. So, prepare:
      inipos = mydiv.style.position;
      inivisibility = mydiv.style.visibility;
      iniz = mydiv.style.zIndex;
      initop = mydiv.style.top;
      inileft = mydiv.style.left;
      inioverflow = mydiv.style.overflow;
      mydiv.style.zIndex = "-999";
      mydiv.style.top = "0";
      mydiv.style.left = "0";
      mydiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
      mydiv.style.position = "fixed";
      mydiv.style.display = "block";
      finHeight = mydiv.clientHeight; // got it!
      // repair damage:
      mydiv.style.display = "none";
      mydiv.style.position = inipos;
      mydiv.style.visibility =     inivisibility;
      mydiv.style.zIndex = iniz;
      mydiv.style.top = initop;
      mydiv.style.left = inileft;

      iniHeight = mydiv.style.height;
      mydiv.style.height = 0;
      mydiv.style.display = "block";
      mydiv.style.overflow="hidden";

      var i = 1;                     //  set your counter to 1
      function myLoop2 (i,mydiv,finHeight,iniHeight,inioverflow) {           //  create a loop function
         setTimeout(function () {    //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called
            mydiv.style.height = finHeight * easeIn(i * (1./fadeDuration));
            i++;                     //  increment the counter
            if (i < fadeDuration) {            //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
               myLoop2(i,mydiv,finHeight,iniHeight,inioverflow);             //  ..  again which will trigger another
            }  else {
                mydiv.style.height = iniHeight;
                mydiv.style.overflow=inioverflow;
            }                       //  ..  setTimeout()
         }, 1)
      }

      myLoop2(i,mydiv,finHeight,iniHeight,inioverflow);


     }

    function slideElementOut(myid) {
      mydiv=    document.getElementById(myid);
      itsdisplay = mydiv.style.display ;
      if ( itsdisplay != "none" ) {

        finHeight = mydiv.clientHeight;
        iniHeight = mydiv.style.height;
        inioverflow = mydiv.style.overflow;
        mydiv.style.overflow = "hidden";
        var i = fadeDuration;                     //  set your counter to 1
        function myLoop (i,mydiv,finHeight,iniHeight,inioverflow) {           //  create a loop function
           setTimeout(function () {    //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called
              mydiv.style.height = finHeight * easeOut(i * (1./fadeDuration));
              i--;                     //  increment the counter
              if (i > 0) {            //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
                 myLoop(i,mydiv,finHeight,iniHeight,inioverflow);             //  ..  again which will trigger another
              }  else {
                  mydiv.style.display = "none";
                  mydiv.style.height = iniHeight;
                  mydiv.style.overflow=inioverflow;
              }                       //  ..  setTimeout()
           }, 1)
        }

        myLoop(i,mydiv,finHeight,iniHeight,inioverflow);

      }


     }
```

I figure it's still worth posting this here, because when I searched for my answer, I got to this question, but needed just a few steps more. I hope this is of help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I recently converted a website to remove its dependencies on jQuery and it used `fadeIn()` and `hide()` for an animated "tab page"-like UI - where if the user clicked on another tab then the current tab page would instantly disappear while the new tab quickly fades in.

I wanted to avoid doing any animation myself in Javascript, especially as CSS3's `transition` and `animation` features are now well-supported. As this question is originally from 2011, I assumed it could do with an update, here's what I used: no jQuery and no manual animations (`setInterval`, `setTimeout`, `requestAnimationFrame`, etc):

From this:

```
<div id="tabContainer">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab" data-tab="tabPage1">Page 1</li>
        <li class="tab" data-tab="tabPage2">Page 2</li>
        <li class="tab" data-tab="tabPage3">Page 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabPage" id="tabPage1"></div>
    <div class="tabPage" id="tabPage2"></div>
    <div class="tabPage" id="tabPage3"></div>
</div>

$('#tabContainer .tab').click(function(e) {
    // when a tab is clicked:

    // 1. Hide all other tabs
    $('#tabContainer .tabPage').hide();

    // 2. Show the selected tab, determined from the clicked element's `data-tab` attribute:
    $( '#' + $(this).data('tab') ).fadeIn();
});
```

(and an 85KB jQuery.min.js download...)

to just this:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#tabContainer .tab');
for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        var tabPages = document.querySelectorAll('#tabContainer .tabPage');
        for(var j=0; j < tabPages.length; j++) {
            tabPages[i].style.display = 'none';
            tabPages[i].classList.remove('animFadeIn');
        }

        var tabToShow = document.querySelector('#' + event.currentTarget.dataset['tab']);
        tabToShow.style.display = '';
        tabToShow.classList.add('animFadeIn');
    });
}
```

And this CSS:

```
.animFadeIn {
    animation: animFadeInAnim 300ms;
}
@keyframes animFadeInAnim {
    0% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
}
```

You cannot use CSS `transition`s because an `opacity` transition is blocked whenever the `display:` property is changed, but CSS animations do support it.

This can be made shorter by replacing the `for(var...` loops with `for(var e of...`, however this kind of loop does not have wide browser support yet (as of June 2016).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following transition function:

```
function transition(style, prop, unit, from, to, duration, callback){
    var change = from-to,
        now = performance.now(),
        end = now + duration;
    function anim8(){
        now = end - performance.now();
        if (now < 0){
            style[prop] = to + unit;
            return callback();
        }

        style[prop] = to + change*now/duration + unit;

        requestAnimationFrame(anim8);
    }
    anim8();
}
```

Example:

```js
transition(
    document.body.style,
    'width',
    'vw',   // unit (appended onto the end)
    95,     // start value
    50,     // end value
    5000,   // duration (miliseconds)
    function(){console.log('done!')} // function to run after finished
);

function transition(style, prop, unit, from, to, duration, callback) {
  var change = from - to,
    now = performance.now(),
    end = now + duration;

  function anim8() {
    now = end - performance.now();
    if (now < 0) {
      style[prop] = to + unit;
      return callback();
    }

    style[prop] = to + change * now / duration + unit;

    requestAnimationFrame(anim8);
  }
  anim8();
}
```

```html
<body style="border:1px solid">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at consequat nisl. Vestibulum tempor dapibus venenatis. Donec sed auctor elit. Suspendisse eget lectus nulla. Pellentesque dapibus tempus tortor, eu cursus ligula iaculis ut. Donec a ipsum elit. Suspendisse gravida fringilla dolor, pulvinar scelerisque ante consectetur vitae.
```

I sometimes find myself using this handy function as opposed to CSS transtions because, lets be honest: CSS transitions were not entirely thought-through. I am not saying that CSS transitions are bad (I sometimes use them), all I am saying is it's hard to use them everywhere. It can often be quite difficult to synchronize voiding the offsetWidth to force a reflow only to end up with a glitchy transition so you then try to setTimeout offset things until it gets unbearably complicated, but still glitchy. For what you use transitions for, you might not have this problem, but for what I use them for, I do have this problem. What they should have included in the spec was an `Element.reflow()` function that will go a step further than just `void Element.offsetWidth`, and actually attempt to synchronize and 'sort-out' the transitions. That single function would have made my job as a dev 10000000000000000000000% easier.

Answer (score -3):

the following is a fadeIn fadeOut animation script.You can use it directly.
Works like a charm in any browser.

```
var TimeToFade = 1000.0;

function fade(eid)
{
  var element = document.getElementById(eid);
  if(element == null)
    return;

  if(element.FadeState == null)
  {
    if(element.style.opacity == null
        || element.style.opacity == ''
        || element.style.opacity == '1')
    {
      element.FadeState = 2;
    }
    else
    {
      element.FadeState = -2;
    }
  }

  if(element.FadeState == 1 || element.FadeState == -1)
  {
    element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 1 ? -1 : 1;
    element.FadeTimeLeft = TimeToFade - element.FadeTimeLeft;
  }
  else
  {
    element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 2 ? -1 : 1;
    element.FadeTimeLeft = TimeToFade;
    setTimeout("animateFade(" + new Date().getTime() + ",'" + eid + "')", 33);
  }
```

Comment: ... where does this script ever set the opacity of an element?

Comment: It doens't... I think, unless FadeState is an ancient Netscape-only property that magically makes the element transparent... Anyway, this snippet of code makes me want to cry myself to sleep. Forcing setTimeout to act as eval is pretty awkward, deprecated, and silly. Extending dom object properties is just about as bad you can get. I believe it forces redoing the element is stored in memory so that it can allow for custom properties. This freezes webpages and increases memory usage. So, instead of posting in an SO form, you might want to try to make a time machine so you can go back the 90's.

Comment: At any rate, this is not a valid answer for 3 reasons. Reason #1 is that Neeraj didn't even post a working code snippet (he failed to include the animateFade function). Reason #2 is that using setTimeout as eval is grossly deprecated, and will likely be removed in the near future, making this solution unsustainable. Reason #3 is that if his code snippet did work, then it wouldn't support IE < 9. Reason #4 is that I have so many reasons against this post that I couldn't fit it all in one comment. Thank you for reading this rant about how this post is in dire need of moderation, and good night.